# How to sibling just the next div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to cible juste the next div with `indented` class name. in the front i have all the next div with `indented` having the same id.

actually, each div with `indented` as a class name, should have the id of the  `<li>` that is right before it.
This is my js :

```
  if ($('.o-commentaires-items').length) {
        var cls = $('.o-commentaires-items').find($(".comment-parent")).attr('id').split(' ')[0];
        number = cls.substr(cls.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
 
        console.log("closest : ", 'collapsee-' + number);
        $('.o-commentaires-items').find($(".comment-parent").next(".indented").addClass("collapse").attr({
            "id":  "collapse-"+number,
            "aria-labelledby":  "heading-"+number
        }));
    }
```

Here the html that the inspector shows in chrome :

```
<ul class="o-commentaires-items accordion">
    <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-137" class="js-ajax-comments-id-137 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-parent by-viewer" data-comment-parent="0">
        test
    </li>
    <div class="indented collapse" id="collapse-137" aria-labelledby="heading-137" style="">
        <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-139" class="js-ajax-comments-id-139 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-137 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="137">
      child 1 
    </li>


        <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-140" class="js-ajax-comments-id-140 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-137 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="137">
      child 2
    </li>
    </div>


  <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-136" class="js-ajax-comments-id-136 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-parent by-viewer" data-comment-parent="0">
    test 2
  </li>
    <div class="indented collapse" id="collapse-137" aria-labelledby="heading-137" style="">
        <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-138" class="js-ajax-comments-id-138 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-136 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="136">
      child 1
    </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<div>` tags as direct child of `<ul>` is invalid HTML

Comment: *"actually, each div with indented as a class name, should have the id of the <li> that is right before it"* this also creates invalid HTML. Please explain what you're trying to achieve instead of what you think would be a technical solution

Comment: @TJ , I do not have a choice i was generated by Drupal

Comment: @TJ, i try to add some attributes(`id`, `aria-labelledby`  and class name : `collapse`) to the `div.indented` tags that are exactly after the `li.comment-parent`

Comment: @mitsu I think what TJ is getting at, is that you will have two identical IDs at that point .  Creating invalid HTML.  Which also affects the way JS and CSS will function on the page ..  What is your **desired output**?

Comment: yes i know, but i can't change it since it was generated by CMS :(

Comment: Hi, so `collapse-137` div > li id should be `comment-137` or `collapse-137` ?

Comment: @Swati actually, it's div.indented that should have the same `id` as `<li>`'s `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the code provided to me by @Swati i was able to fin a solution:

```
if ($('.o-commentaires-items').length) {
    //loop
    $(".indented").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).prev(".comment-parent").attr("id"))
        //get first li attr id
        var id = $(this).prev(".comment-parent").attr("id").split('-')[1];
        //add attrs..
        $(this).addClass("collapse").attr({
            "id": "collapse-" + id,
            "aria-labelledby": "heading-" + id
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each` loop to iterate through all `indented` div then using `:first` get first li inside that div . Then, simply add attributes to your elements i.e : `.attr()`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
if ($('.o-commentaires-items').length) {
  //loop 
  $(".indented").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("li:first").attr("id"))
    //get first li attr id
    var id = $(this).find("li:first").attr("id").split('-')[1]
    //add attrs..
    $(this).addClass("collapse").attr({
      "id": "collapse-" + id,
      "aria-labelledby": "heading-" + id
    });
  })
}
```

```css
.collapse {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="o-commentaires-items accordion">
  <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-137" class="js-ajax-comments-id-137 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-parent by-viewer" data-comment-parent="0">
    test
  </li>
  <div class="indented collapse" id="collapse-137" aria-labelledby="heading-137" style="">
    <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-139" class="js-ajax-comments-id-139 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-137 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="137">
      child 1
    </li>
    <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-140" class="js-ajax-comments-id-140 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-137 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="137">
      child 2
    </li>
  </div>


  <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-136" class="js-ajax-comments-id-136 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-parent by-viewer" data-comment-parent="0">
    test 2
  </li>
  <div class="indented collapse" id="collapse-137" aria-labelledby="heading-137" style="">
    <li data-comment-user-id="1" id="comment-138" class="js-ajax-comments-id-138 contextual-region js-comment o-commentaires-item comment-child comment-parent-136 by-viewer" data-comment-parent="136">
      child 1
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: the div with the className `indented` does not have the same id as `<li>` before it

Comment: but thanks to your help @Swati, i was able to find the solution, i will post it in a now Post

Comment: :P i have misunderstood your question sorry .